# Jquery, formatting in a textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been working on an extension at work and the only thing that is escaping me is formatting a textarea based on three inputs that i combine and try to make a new line per enter on the last input. It works for the first two lines then the new lines start adding up going to two lines between submissions then 4 etc.

```
$("#misc").keyup(function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var newText = $('#medication').val() + " " + $('#diagnosis').val() + " " + $('#misc').val();

        $("#form").val($("#form").val() + newText + "\r\n");

        nextBox = textboxes[0];
        nextBox.focus();
        nextBox.select();
        console.log("first");
        $('#medication').val("");
        $('#diagnosis').val("");
        $('#misc').val("");

        return false;
    }
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated
https://jsfiddle.net/rcu8dmon/ this is kinda what it looks like but its not working in the jsfiddle for some reason.

Edited to add the jsfiddle for the html/css/javascript

Comment: Could you add the corresponding HTML?

Comment: added a jsfiddle to show html

Comment: You need to specify that you want jquery in your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rcu8dmon/1/

Comment: Make sure you only bind the keyup event once - currently it's bound multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are binding the `#misc`'s `keyup` event every time when the `.medication`'s `keyup` event occurs, so it happens n times when `#misc`'s `keyup` event occurs. Move the `#misc`'s `keyup` event outside the wrapping event, and it'll be fixed.

Comment: It is still adding a lot of extra spaces. From what i can see it seems to do the same thing I am attempting.

Comment: maybe you are re-assigning the event when it happens? The event runs once, normal. twice, one extra line but you won't realise. 4 times, now 3 extra lines etc.

Comment: http://screencast.com/t/mW2Awqlc this is what it looks like for reference.

Comment: read my previous comment. I guess you're doing what I've said.

Comment: The fiddle binds an event inside another event, so it's likely the second event is getting bound multiple times.

Comment: Yes, I didn't see the fiddle but it seems so. I'll update my answer.

Comment: I tried using both the options you provided, i see the error of binding multiple times but how should I go from here?

Comment: I've changed my answer.

Comment: That was it! Thanks freedomn-m and Taha Paksu both of you were very helpful! I've never asked a question on here before, is there a way to close the question and give credit?

Comment: nvm, figured that out by myself ;) u2 have a great day

Answer (score 0):

Also your medication class in keyup event is triggered in the last imput too. You try to fix this, validating the last imput, but you compare a type "undefined" with null. An option it's simply remove "!== null": 
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp

```
if (textboxes[currentBoxNumber + 1])
```